# Dynamically reinit range of y-axis?

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

Is it possible to dynamically reinit the Range of the Y-Axis by calling a method on the renderer after adding new Series to the Graph ? Or should i detect the min and max values by myself and then set the Y Axis min and max value manually ? I recognized that the repaint function does not automatically rescale the ranges of the axis, so my graphs went off screen if the points does not fit in the current displayed range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will automatically rescale if you create a new instance of `XYMultipleSeriesDataset` and add new `XYSeries`. Otherwise you will have to update your Y axis range manually.